# How to delete user id from array and vacate spot without it copying?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So for my C++ program I need to delete my user ID based on date. Hence for example if a user has been in the system for longer than 6 months then we delete them.

i have a struct for user.

//so struct user[5] for my array.

//int pos = 0;

example of a user ids:

**id:** 0001

**name:** helen

**age:** 25

**date joined:** 25/4/2019

**date left:** 16/5/2019

**id:** 0002

**name:** jai

**age:** 28

**date joined :** 20/2/2017

date left:0/0/0000

this is my code for the delete function :

```
void delete()
{
    if (pos > 0)
    {

        int id;

        cout << "Enter user ID: ";
        cin >> id;

        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        {
            if (t[i].id == id)
            {
                if (t[i].d1 == 0 && t[i].m1 == 0 && t[i].y1 == 0)
                {
                    cout << "\nDate left not set\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nDate left: " << t[i].d1 << "/" << t[i].m1 << "/" << t[i].y1 << "\n";

                    int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;

                    cout << "Enter date: ";
                    cin >> day >> month >> year;

                    if (day < t[i].d1)
                    {
                        if (month == 3)
                        {
                            if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
                            {
                                day += 29;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                day += 28;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 10 || month == 12)
                        {
                            day += 30;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            day += 31;
                        }
                    }

                    if (month < t[i].m1)
                    {
                        month += 12;
                        year -= 1;
                    }

                    int totalY = 0, totalM = 0, totalD = 0;

                    totalD = day - t[i].d1;
                    totalM = month - t[i].m1;
                    totalY = year - t[i].y1;

                    if (totalY >= 1)
                    {

                        if (totalM >= 6)
                        {
                            cout << "\nDiscard\n";
                            for (int j = i; j < 5-1 ; j++)
                            {
                                t[j] = t[j + 1];

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "\nDiscard\n";
                            for (int j = i; j < 5-1 ; j++)
                            {
                                t[j] = t[j + 1];

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (totalY == 0)
                    {
                        if (totalM >= 6)
                        {
                            cout << "\nDiscard\n";
                            for (int j = i; j < 5-1 ; j++)
                            {
                                t[j] = t[j + 1];

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "\nNo changes\n";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "\nNo changes\n";
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }

            if (i == pos - 1)
            {
                cout << "\nNot found\n";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nNo record\n";
    }
}
```

my issue is happening that it does delete the record however, it doesn't leave a space in the array if i want to enter more records but ends up duplicating the last record.

if i delete user 0001 then it will just duplicate 0002 twice. How can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 2):

You must decrement the variable `pos` after deleting every record.

Comment: That doesn't achieve the request to **vacate spot without copying**, but the OP seems happy.

Comment: Actually now I think about it, your answer is the correct one. What the OP means by without copying is the duplication he noticed. I thought he meant without copying elements in the array,

Comment: can u explain the term **vacate spot without copying**.

Comment: yeah without copying he just swap the deleting element with the last element and decrement length.

Comment: i had 5 user ids
001
002
003
004
005

so when i deleted 002
it became like this 

001
003
004
005
005

Comment: @RanjithThangaraju That works, but I think the OP request is very simple and your answer does what he wants. He just expressed himself in a way that confused me.

Answer (score 2):

First comment is that is an excessively long function whch combines lots of different functionalities. You should break it down, so that you have one function to enter a date, another function to validate a date, another function to compare two dates, and finally a function to delete a user. It's only by breaking down functions into smaller pieces that you will get to *reuse* functions in different parts of your code. Also smaller functions will make the code much easier to understand.

As for your actual question you need to mark the user as deleted. You haven't said what your struct looks like, but assuming it''s something like this

```
struct User
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};
```

you should change it to this

```
struct User
{
    string name;
    int id;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    bool deleted; // true if this user has been deleted, false otherwise
};
```

Then all you need to do is

```
t[i].deleted =  true;
```

This is called *marking for deletion*.

Then in the rest of your code you need to add a check to see if a user has been deleted and take the appropriate action if they have.

Finally you probably need to periodically really delete users from you array, not just mark them for deletion. For instance when the array has filled up and you want to add a new user.

Comment: Ah yes that's similar to my struct, it was a very small issue so I was able to solve it through decrementing pos.